# pandas data frame comparing string values for 2 group by columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a data set that looks like this-

```
ID        Search    Provider
1           Yes     A
1           Yes     B
1           No      B
1           No      C
2           Yes     D
2           Yes     A
2           Yes     B
2           No      B
2           No      C
```

What I want to find out is if the Providers for `Search==Yes` is different from `Search==No` for a given ID. E.g.- 'ID 1', 'Search=No' goes to Providers B,C whereas 'Search=Yes' goes to Providers A,B. So the provider A is new for ID 1.

I know I can use the `isin` function to identify the unique values between two lists. However, how do I do it across multiple rows of ID and Search? And how do I compile the Provider values into lists for each subgroup defined by ID and Search? I guess I will need to use nested loops but not being able to write the code. Would really appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Comment: Not 100% sure of your desired output. But seems like you want to split then you can `outer` `merge` with an indicator to figure out which providers exist in both, only Yes or only No. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than compiling into lists, you might want to consider sets. In a generic sense, this might be more useful as I would assume order and redundancy doesn't matter. Also, it's easier to determine which providers are in one set and not another. You can rearrange your dataframe with `pivot_table` to do this:

```
df_new = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Search', aggfunc=set).droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
Search      No        Yes
ID                       
1       {C, B}     {A, B}
2       {C, B}  {D, A, B}
```

With this new dataframe, you can compare values with the same 'ID' easiliy:

```
# df_new['No'] == df_new['Yes']   # If providers are the same between "yes" and "no"
df_new['Yes'] - df_new['No']      # Providers that are in "yes" but not "no"
```

Result (for set difference):

```
ID
1       {A}
2    {D, A}
dtype: object
```

Comment: Amazing! this is exactly what I needed. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a few steps.  First, group by ID and search, then get the unique values with value_counts.

```
>>> df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Search']).Provider.value_counts()
ID  Search  Provider
1   No      B           1
            C           1
    Yes     A           1
            B           1
2   No      B           1
            C           1
    Yes     A           1
            B           1
            D           1
```

For each ID/Provider combination, you can then get a count of the number of Yes/No Searches

```
>>> df2 = df1.unstack(level='Search', fill_value=0)
Search       No  Yes
ID Provider         
1  A          0    1
   B          1    1
   C          1    0
2  A          0    1
   B          1    1
   C          1    0
   D          0    1
```

From here, you can get the list of Provider/ID combos that have either Yes or No but not both

```
>>> df2 = df1.query('Yes != No')
Search       No  Yes
ID Provider         
1  A          0    1
   C          1    0
2  A          0    1
   C          1    0
   D          0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

You can use `groupby.agg(set)` first, then again `groupby.diff`:

```
dfg = df.groupby(['ID', 'Search']).agg(set).reset_index()
dfg.groupby('ID')['Provider'].diff().dropna()

1       {A}
3    {A, D}
Name: Provider, dtype: object`
```

---

**Method 2**

Splitting the dataset up in `yes` and `no` then `groupby.set`:

```
yes = df.loc[df['Search'] == 'Yes']
no  = df.loc[df['Search'] == 'No']

yes_agg = yes.groupby('ID')['Provider'].agg(set)
no_agg = no.groupby('ID')['Provider'].agg(set)

# get the difference between the sets
yes_agg - no_agg

ID
1       {A}
2    {A, D}
Name: Provider, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me! Really appreciate it!